# Convert draw2d.Workflow to html canvas element

Tags: image, canvas, workflow

in documentation I read that a workflow has method getDocument() who returns a draw2d.CanvasDocument. A property of CanvasDocument is canvas object, but it is not the html canvas element obviously. There is a way to convert my workflow in html canvas? My goal is to convert workflow in static image, and a canvas element can be easily converted to static image. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for Draw2D it is not possible to convert the Draw2DCanvas to a image. Reason: Draw2d use plain HTML (not HTML5) to create the workflows and lines as well.

If you need a image -> [Graphiti is your hero](http://draw2d.org/graphiti/jsdoc/#!/example/io_png_overview).

available in the next days.

Comment: thanks...convert my js classes to Graphiti is a long and hard process?